# The text after await cannot be printed out in async void method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Recently I'm learning Task and certailly I touched async await, and i tried to write a simple demo, please kindly help check whether there are any problems in my coding? And why the "x=???" and "GetDataFromDbAsync ends" not be printed on console? I would much appreicate if you could help me out. Thanks a lot.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Test test = new Test();
            Console.WriteLine("main thread starts...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            test.GetDataFromDb();
            Console.WriteLine("Mainthread end");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        public void GetDataFromDb()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetDataFromDb starts");
            Task.Run(() => GetDataFromDbAsync());
            Console.WriteLine("GetDataFromDb ends");
        }

        public async Task<bool> GetDataFromDbAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GetDataFromDbAsync starts");
                var x = await ReadingDbAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("x=" + x);
                Console.WriteLine("GetDataFromDbAsync ends");
                return true;
            }
            catch(AggregateException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public Task<int> ReadingDbAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ReadingDbAsync starts");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            var task= new Task<int>(() => 100);
            Console.WriteLine("ReadingDbAsync ends");
            return task;
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the output,
[demo output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugIeE.jpg)

Output as following：

```
main thread starts...
GetDataFromDb starts
GetDataFromDb end
Mainthread end
GetDataFromDbAsync starts
ReadingDbAsync starts
ReadingDbAsync ends
**BUT WHY NOT SHOW THE FOLLOWING
x=100
GetDataFromDbAsync ends**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using the task constructor:

```
var task= new Task<int>(() => 100);
```

If you want a task that represents a synchronous value, use `Task.FromResult`:

```
var task = Task.FromResult(100);
```

As I describe on my blog, [you should never, ever use task constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Answer (score 1):

You're not `await`ing the task you're creating in `GetDataFromDb`.  As a result, the execution will hit `Console.ReadKey` before state machine resumes after the `await` in `GetDataFromDbAsync`.  I suspect if you hit a key, you'll see your two missing console messages before the application exits.

You need to return a `Task` `GetDataFromDb` and ensure it has completed:

```
test.GetDataFromDb().Wait();
```

Also, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630506/async-at-console-app-in-c)