# Understanding the use of Task.Run + Wait() + async + await used in one line

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm a C# newbie, so I'm struggling to understand some concepts, and I run into a piece of code that I'm not quite understanding:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 Task.Run(async () => { await SomeClass.Initiate(new Configuration()); }).Wait();
 while (true) ;
}
```

As I understand, this runs a task which initiates a method. This method runs, and then, once it finished, it gets into an infinite loop waiting. It feels that either the code doesn't make sense, or that I'm not understanding right.

Comment: It is forcing an async method `SomeClass.Initiate` to be executed synchronously. The Task.Run wrapping the async method is not needed. The infinite loop is to prevent the console window from closing immediately after completing `Initiate`. Where did this code come from, is there any context for it?

Comment: There are better pieces of code to "run into" for running async methods in console app  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630506/async-at-console-app-in-c

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can break this apart into several parts:

```
async () => { await SomeClass.Initiate(new Configuration()); }
```

Is a lambda expression that defines an `async` method that just awaits another method. This lambda is then passed to `Task.Run`:

```
Task.Run(async () => { await SomeClass.Initiate(new Configuration()); })
```

`Task.Run` executes its code on a thread pool thread. So, that `async` lambda will be run on a thread pool thread. `Task.Run` returns a `Task` which represents the execution of the `async` lambda. After calling `Task.Run`, the code calls `Task.Wait`:

```
Task.Run(async () => { await SomeClass.Initiate(new Configuration()); }).Wait();
```

This will block the main console app until the async lambda is completely finished.

If you want to see how it's broken out further, the following is roughly equivalent:

```
static async Task AnonymousMethodAsync()
{
  await SomeClass.Initiate(new Configuration());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var task = Task.Run(() => AnonymousMethodAsync());
  task.Wait();
  while (true) ;
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `while(true)` at the very end though?

Comment: @information_interchange: It was in the op's original code.

Comment: @StephenCleary what is the reason someone would write code like this? Is it equivalent to `SomeClass.Initiate(new Configuration()).Result`?

Comment: @TomDane: The original code is attempting to do sync-over-async. While sync-over-async used to be common in a console app `Main` method, these days `Main` can be `async`, so it's no longer necessary.

Comment: While this answer breaks down each line it does not point out that Task.Run() is completely unnecessary with Wait(). One of the main reasons to use Task.Run() is to run the task in a different thread without blocking the main thread. But the Wait() blocks the main thread and hence there are two threads used for a single task.
If Wait() should be used, then this is what should be used:
`SomeClass.Initiate(new Configuration()).Wait();`

Comment: @A.G.: For the code posted, your analysis is correct. However, the most common use of the `Task.Run(...).Wait()` pattern is to avoid deadlocks in situations with a one-thread-at-a-time `SynchronizationContext`. It is likely that the OP came across this code somewhere _other_ than a `Main` method and just simplified it to a Console app in the question. In those situations, the `Task.Run` is not unnecessary; it is used to side-step the `SynchronizationContext`. I didn't address this in my answer (along with the fact that this deadlock workaround is not the best solution), since OP is new to C#.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a little [**.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cVLTjS) that simply added some `Console.WriteLine` calls to hopefully help show you the order of execution.

The [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `Task` that represents an asynchronous operation, (a method that runs asynchronously). It's parameter in this situation is the `Func<Task>`. Your code has utilized the `async` and `await` keywords, as such your call to `SomeClass.Initiate` is an async lambda.

> Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a proxy for the task returned by function.

*All async code should return an awaitable, unless in the rare situation where you're authoring an event handler that needs to start some async calls.*

The `Task` that is returned from the invocation of `Task.Run` is immediately invoking [`.Wait()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Waits for the Task to complete execution within a specified time interval.

That call to `Task.Run` is not needed, you could simply invoke `.Wait()` on the `Task` that is returned from the `SomeClass.Initiate` method.

As for the infinite loop, a console application exits immediately -- you could simply do the `Console.ReadLine` and wait for the user to hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for example.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely `SomeClass.Initiate` is synchronous method marked `async` for no reason. Than someone tried to make it really run asynchronously and added `Task.Run` to run it on separate thread. But since it is console application - added `.Wait()` to wait for the operation to finish.

And `while (true) ;` is there because when running in VS console app closes without trace when it is done, more obvious way - add `Console.ReadLine()` call. `while(true)` is not realated to async portion at all as code will not leave `.Wait()` call before operation is done.

Another possibility is author was experimenting with `async` and did not have `.Wait()` or `.Result` - thus `while(true)` would give chance for operation to finish.

See [async at console app in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630506/async-at-console-app-in-c) for proper way to run async code in console app (just `.Wait()` or `.Result`)