# Trying to Understand Task.Run + async + Wait()/Result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I'm trying to understand how Task.Run + Wait() + async + await work.
I have read this page: [Understanding the use of Task.Run + Wait() + async + await used in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622528/understanding-the-use-of-task-run-wait-async-await-used-in-one-line) but don't understand it quite well.

In my code, I receive events from Microsoft EventHub and process them using a class that implements `IEventProcessor`.
I call `DoAnotherWork()` method, which is an `async` method, in `ConvertToEntity()`, which is a sync method.
Since the method is `async`, I use `Task.Run()` and `async` to delegate. (i.e. `Task.Run(async () => entities = await DoAnotherWork(entities)).Wait()`)
The code has been working for a while but now my team member removed `Task.Run()` and changed it to `DoAnotherWork(entities).Result;`. I'm not sure this won't cause deadlocks.
I haven't asked him why he changed it but this change got me thinking "Is my code fine? Why?".

My questions are:
 * What is the difference between the two?
 * Which code is appropriate and/or safe (= won't cause a deadlock)?
 * In what situation is a deadlock caused if it is?
 * Why `Task.Run()` resolve deadlock I had? (see below for detail)

Note: I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

*Why I Use Task.Run()*
My team had deadlock issues a few times when we used `AbcAsync().Result` or `.Wait()` (the method was called in a NET Core Web API methods and deadlocks occurred mostly when we ran unit tests that execute the method), so we've used `Task.Run(async () => await AbcAsync()).Wait()/Result` and we haven't seen any deadlock issues since then.
However, this page: https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d says that the delagation will cause a deadloock in certain conditions.

```
public class EventProcessor : IEventProcessor
{
    public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages) 
    {
        ...
        var result = await eventHandler.ProcessAsync(messages);
        ...
    }
}

public Task async ProcessAsync(IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
{
    ...
    var entities = ConvertToEntity(messages);
    ...
}

public List<Entity> ConvertToEntity(IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
{
    var serializedMessages = Serialize(messages);
    var entities = autoMapper.Map<Entity[]>(serializedMessages);

    // Task.Run(async () => entities = await DoAnotherWork(entities)).Wait(); // before change
    entities = DoAnotherWork(entities).Result; // after change

    return entities;
}    

public Task async Entity[] DoAnotherWork(Entity[] entities)
{
    // Do stuff async
    await DoMoreStuff(entities)...
}
```

Comment: Also, by the way, deadlock usually occur when two threads end up waiting for the same resource, or for each other, and one of the two threads never finishes or moves forward.

Comment: Joe Albahari's excellent and free [eBook on Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism) explains all of this in great detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two?

`Task.Run` starts running the delegate on a thread pool thread; invoking the method directly [starts running the delegate on the current thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

When learning `async`, it's helpful to separate out everything so you can see exactly what's going on:

```
entities = DoAnotherWork(entities).Result;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var entitiesTask = DoAnotherWork(entities);
entities = entitiesTask.Result;
```

and this code:

```
Task.Run(async () => entities = await DoAnotherWork(entities)).Wait();
```

is equivalent to:

```
async Task LambdaAsMethod()
{
  entities = await DoAnotherWork(entities);
}
var runTask = Task.Run(LambdaAsMethod);
runTask.Wait();
```

> Which code is appropriate and/or safe (= won't cause a deadlock)?

[You should avoid `Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net) in an ASP.NET environment because it will interfere with the ASP.NET handling of the thread pool and force a thread switch when none is necessary.

> In what situation is a deadlock caused if it is?

The [common deadlock scenario](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) requires two things:

1. Code that blocks on asynchronous code instead of properly using `await`.
2. A context that enforces synchronization (i.e., only allows one block of code "in" the context at a time).

The *best* solution is to remove the first condition; in other words, use ["`async` all the way"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). To apply that here, the best resolution is to remove the blocking completely:

```
public Task async ProcessAsync(IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
{
    ...
    var entities = await ConvertToEntityAsync(messages);
    ...
}

public async Task<List<Entity>> ConvertToEntityAsync(IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
{
    var serializedMessages = Serialize(messages);
    var entities = autoMapper.Map<Entity[]>(serializedMessages);

    entities = await DoAnotherWork(entities);

    return entities;
}
```

> Why Task.Run() resolve deadlock I had? (see below for detail)

[.NET Core does not have a "context" at all](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html), so it uses the thread pool context. Since .NET Core doesn't have a context, it removes the second condition for the deadlock, and the deadlock will not occur. **If** you're running this in an ASP.NET Core project.

> My team had deadlock issues a few times when we used AbcAsync().Result or .Wait() (the method was called in a NET Core Web API methods and deadlocks occurred mostly when we ran unit tests that execute the method)

Some unit test frameworks *do* provide a context - most notably xUnit. The context provided by xUnit *is* a synchronizing context, so it acts more like a UI context or ASP.NET pre-Core context. So when your code is running in a unit test, it does have the second condition for the deadlock, and the deadlock can happen.

As noted above, the *best* solution is to remove the blocking completely; this will have the nice side effect of making your server more efficient. But if the blocking *must* be done, then you should wrap your *unit test* code in a `Task.Run`, not your ASP.NET Core code.