# How to upload file to blob container?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to learn how to use blobs. With this code I want to upload my text file. I do not get errors. All that hapens is that the file is not found in the container. And I have read previous similar questions but none used this method.

What am I missing here?

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Upload_it_Async();
        }

        private static async void Upload_it_Async()
        {

        var filepath = @"C:\my_file.txt";
        var connectionString = ***********;
        var containerName = "my_container";

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        var container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        var blockBlob = container.GetBlobClient("my_file.txt");
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await blockBlob.UploadAsync(fs);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: _" I do not get errors."_ You probably do, you just cannot "see" them. Use `async Task` instead of `async void` and try this: `Upload_it_Async().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` for a start. Then you should get exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to wait for that task to complete:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Upload_it_Async().Wait();
}

//Change the method to Task, not void:
private static async Task Upload_it_Async()
...
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630506/async-at-console-app-in-c#) for more discussion around async usage in console applications.

As noted in the comments, doing this will ensure any exceptions are thrown in your `Main` method.

Answer (score -1):

Suggest use below code snippet.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  await Upload_it_Async();
}

private static async Task Upload_it_Async()
```

And here are two good Azure StorageBlob Samples you can take a reference. And if you have any questions about Azure Storage, please be free let me know.

[sample1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-net-storage-blob-upload-download/blob/master/v12/Program.cs)

[sample2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples/Sample01b_HelloWorldAsync.cs)